# Finding eigenvalues of block type matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

If I know the eigenvalues of matrix $A$, is there any way to calculate eigenvalues of $B$ using some tricks? Here $A$ is an $m\times m$, $O$ is the zero matrix and $I$ denotes $m \times m$ identity matrix. I want to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix $B$.

$B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
A & I-kI \\
I & O \end{array} \right) $.

Here $k$ is any positive integer. I tried to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix $B$ by taking $k=1$. But I could not anything relevant. Is it possible to find any relation between eigenvalues of $B$  and eigenvalues of $A$? What can be said if $A$ is a symmetric matrix?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of B can be found by the expression:

$$ \det \left(
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & I-kI \\
I & O \end{array} \right)
-
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\lambda I & O \\
O & \lambda I \end{array} \right)
\right)
=
\det \left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
A-\lambda I & I-kI \\
I & -\lambda I \end{array}
\right) 
=
0$$

There are relations for [calculating the determinant of a block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices):

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(A)\times  \det\left(D - C A^{-1} B\right) = \det(D)\times  \det\left(A - B D^{-1} C\right)$$

$$
\det \left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
A-\lambda I & I-kI \\
I & -\lambda I \end{array}
\right)
=
\det(A-\lambda I)\times  \det\left(-\lambda I -  (A-\lambda I)^{-1} (I-kI)\right)
=
\det(-\lambda I)\times  \det\left( (A-\lambda I) - (I-kI) (-\lambda I)^{-1} \right)
=
0$$

Looking into the first equation, when $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is equal to zero which means that $(A-\lambda I)$ is not invertible and this equation can't be used.

On the other hand, the second equation is only valid if $\lambda$ is different from zero. So if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are different from zero and $k=1$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are also eigenvalues of $B$.